# Is it possible to run OcuSDK on some simulator or flat screen without headset hardware?

Tags: oculus-rift

I downloaded the OCUSDK and have been reading thru it. I don't yet have DK2. Is it possible to run the sample code on any simulator or any display without having the headset?

If this is possible, please give me a hint.

thanks in advance.

Comment: No;  A simulator has not been created yet.  You will need the physical hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Oculus runtime (current version is 0.8) and select Tools, Service, Configure... then in the [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp9HS.png) you can select "DK2" in the "Debug HMD Type" combo box. This will make it appear to any Oculus application like you have a DK2 connected. Obviously you won't have head tracking but otherwise the applications should run normally. Depending on the application you may have to set it to mirror mode (though most default to this).